# Java - Slicing a string into multiple strings in one pass

Tags: java, string, split, slice

I am reading a table from a PDF file using PDFBox. The table is a bit complicated (some parts has more columns than others, has split boxes, etc.) so the data isn't perfectly structured. However I have managed to get the data structured *enough* so I can extract the important bits from it.

Due to the nature of the data, I want to split a string (representing a row of data  from all the columns) into multiple parts, representing each column. I want to do this before I get rid of the whitespace, because the format of the table must be maintained and some columns may be empty. For example :

```
  Monday            Tuesday         Wednesday

 Spaghetti         Salad               Apple
  Meatballs                          Sandwich
 Garlic Bread       Chicken            Cheese
```

You can see the data isn't perfectly aligned, and there may be whitespaces such as the second row on Tuesday that must be maintained. My plan is to hardcode slice each column (say, up to 20 characters for each column, **size of each column might differ**), before getting rid of the whitespace.

My question is, what is the fastest and most efficient way to slice a String into an array of Strings? I could use String.substring() but I would rather not do that for each column. Is there a way to do this all in one pass?

Comment: What is bad about `substring`? You want to slice one big String object into many smaller String objects. `substring` creates one of these smaller String objects - something you're going to have to do in any case. I don't see any overhead or bad thing about using `substring` for this.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt But if you use `substring` you are going to need to find the offsets

Comment: I just implemented my own function to split the columns manually (iterating through each char) instead of using string.substring(). The problem with using string.substring() is that its runtime is O(n), not O(1). So obviously I'm not splitting the lines in one pass if I just call string.substring() multiple times to split the columns.

Comment: @JohnKim Worrying about substring being O(N) in a scenario like this **screams** premature optimization, specially considering `String` is a core component of Java with methods that are likely already highly optimized in any decent implementation of the JVM. I doubt anything you write in Java can outperform native `String` functions. Finally, it's also unclear how anything that iterates through each char can be O(1)

Comment: @JohnKim Ehm. Before Java9, `substring` was definitely `O(1)`. Now with compressed strings it's a bit trickier - but, that will be the case for *any* method that you're going to use to make multiple strings, it's not caused by `substring`

Comment: @NullUserException sure, what's bad about that? If you want to split a string you're going to need to know where you want to split the string. And the OP already knows how to do it, from what I read - first split into lines, then split into 20-character wide columns.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt If he's going to slice the lines into fixed size 20-char columns, then yeah, substring is perfect. But he'd still need to perform some clean up afterwards since the columns have variable lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `String.trim` and `String.split` (on whitespace, for example):

```
String s = "  Monday            Tuesday         Wednesday  ";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.trim().split("\\s+")));
```

Output:

```
[Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday]
```

You do this for each line. You can tell if a line is blank, because the resulting array will have size 0.